# Display and autoplay youtube video in popup on document load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to autoplay a youtube video in a popup 5 seconds after document load, unfortunately, it's not working:

I took this code from a tutorial, where the video was played on click, but what I actually need is for the video to be displayed automatically after the page loads, without any action from the user. I tried modifying the code myself by adding `$(document).ready` but unfortunately, it's not working as expected.
Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"; 
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '315',
                width: '560',
                videoId: 'jNQXAC9IVRw',
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }


        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                //player is playing
            } else {
                //player is paused
            }
        }

        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }

        function playVideo() {
            player.playVideo();
        }

        function pauseVideo() {
            player.pauseVideo();
        }


        $(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function() {
            playVideo();
        });

        $(document).on('closed.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function() {
            pauseVideo();
        });
    }, 5000); // 5000 to load it after 5 seconds from page load
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <h2>Video</h2>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
  </div>
```

---

**EDIT**

I've added jQuery but the video is not loading and not playing, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the video is not autoplaying? That may because of the [autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Below are the point from above link -

Chrome's autoplay policies are simple:

1. Muted autoplay is always allowed.
2. Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

   a. User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).

   b. On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.

   c.The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.
3. Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.

You can just mute the player to ensure it is autoplayed.

I just copied the code from [youtube iframe_api reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and muted the player on player ready and it works -

Please check below code -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    
    <div id="player"></div>
  </div>

</div>

    <script>
    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
            player.mute();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    $("#myModal").find(".modal-content .close").click(function(){
     $("#myModal").hide();
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#myModal").show();
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        }, 5000); // 5000 to load it after 5 seconds from page load
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Temporary fiddle link for the same - [Youtube video muted autoplay](https://jsfiddle.net/y0mt4jnr/)

[Fiddle for video in popup](https://jsfiddle.net/0fk12znu/)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get it to be in a pop-up?

Comment: @julia2019, What do you mean in pop-up? Do you a modal popup using bootstrap or something? Also, I realized you wanted the video to be played on document ready and after 5 seconds timeout, so I have updated the snipper and jsfiddle accordingly.

Comment: @julia2019, fiddle to show video in popup - https://jsfiddle.net/0fk12znu/. Note popup will open after 5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to *call* this function:

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
```

at some point; otherwise the `player` will never be initialized, so the video will never load.

Also, this function call is the only thing that needs to go *inside* the `setTimeout` function. You'll want everything else to be initialized and ready *before* you call this function.

So this should work for you:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
}, 5000);
```

and move the rest of your code *outside* of the `setTimeout`.